# how can i provide image library path for imagemagick

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using ImageMagick library in CodeIgniter for re-sizing and rotating image using image library. But its generating error. The error is -"The path to your image library is not correct. Please set the correct path in your image preferences."

```
$config = array();
$config['image_library']  = 'ImageMagick';
$config['source_image']   = $file;
$config['new_image']      =  $file;
$config['create_thumb']   = FALSE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']          = 50;
$config['height']         = 50;
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);  

if ( !$this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo "resize -".$this->image_lib->display_errors();
} 
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

Below has given me expected result. Hope you will also get same.

```
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    //For resizing of image in size of dilog
    $config['image_library']  = 'ImageMagick';
    $config['library_path'] = 'C:\\ImageMagick\\';

    $config['source_image'] = $source_filepath;
    $config['new_image'] = $new_filepath;

    $config['width'] = 128;
    $config['height'] = 128;
    $config['quality'] = '100%';
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if (! $this->image_lib->resize()) {
        $error_msg = $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        print_r($error_msg);
    }
    else {
        echo "Done";
    }
```

Here

```
$config['library_path'] = 'C:\\ImageMagick\\';
```

is the path for windows where your imageMagick application is installed.(Try to install in such a folder to which we can easily map it for library path).
Change the image library to :

```
$config['image_library']  = 'ImageMagick';
```

& other all configuration is remains same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not giving correct path basically imagemagick is installed somewhere ideally in /user/bin. When I worked I use to give like this

```
imageMagickConvert = /usr/bin/convert 
imageMagickComposite = /usr/bin/composite
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin';
```

add this line in your config.